# Passing data between two controllers in angularjs gets cleared when the page is refreshed

Tags: angularjs

I am using the following service to pass data between two controllers

```
app.service('sharedDataService', function () {

    var selectedObj = {};

    var setSelectedObj = function (obj) {
        selectedObj = obj;
    };

    var getSelectedObj = function () {
        return selectedObj;
    };

    return {
        SetSelectedObj: setSelectedObj,
        GetSelectedObj: getSelectedObj
    };
});
```

It works fine except when on the 2nd controller, the users press F5 or refresh the browser page. The selectedObj is cleared returns null.

**Edit:** based on some answers and comments - I am saving the data in the 2nd controller when I use the following line

```
$scope.Form = sharedDataService.GetSelectedObj();
```

Do I need to save it differently?

Comment: this is an expected behavior, use local storage if you want to keep information

Comment: @LuninRoman please see the edited question, I am saving the object in the 2nd controller, so some reason after refresh getselectedObj returns null.

Answer (score 0):

After getting the result please add it in session, after page refresh you can access those values again, even we can't root scope variable as well because those also cleared after page refresh.

Comment: How do I add it in session ?

Comment: It was my bad, instead of session, you need to add in cookie from front end.
I am sure it'll work for you